# Learning C, and getting errors (I think mostly syntax, but I'm learning!)

Tags: c, syntax, struct

This program simply takes a file with ASCII lines, puts it into a linked-list stack, and then prints the reversed list to a new file in the same ASCII format.

My struct Code:

```
typedef struct Node{
char *info[15];
struct Node *ptr;
};
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Errors:
    strrev.c:14: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
    strrev.c: In function ‘main’:
    strrev.c:28: error: ‘Node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    strrev.c:28: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    strrev.c:28: error: for each function it appears in.)
    strrev.c:28: error: ‘head’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    strrev.c:34: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
```

/usr/include/string.h:128: note: expected ‘char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

My main program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: intrev <input file> <output file>\n");
    exit(1);
    }

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);


Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
head->ptr=NULL;

char str[15];
while (fgets(str, 15, fp) != NULL){
    struct Node *currNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(currNode->info, str);
    currNode->ptr = head;
    head=currNode;
}

char *outfile = argv[2];
FILE *outfilestr = fopen(outfile, "w");
assert(fp != NULL);

while (head->ptr != NULL){
    fprintf(outfilestr, "%s\n", head->info);
    head = head->ptr;
}

fclose(fp);
fclose(outfilestr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think a lot of these errors have to do with my Struct, but I don't know what I did wrong there...

Comment: Tip: focus on the first error, post your whole code in one piece, and tell us very clearly which line has the first error.

Comment: Since you are still learning: strong advice to not use typedefs until you really need them. Typedefs might save you some typing, but the resulting code is much harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to reference your struct within your struct:

```
struct Node {
  char info[15];
  struct Node *ptr;
};
```

When you make a struct you have to typeout `struct Node` in order to use it.  If you want to avoid that you can make a typedef

```
typedef struct Node {
  char info[15];
  struct Node *ptr;
} Node;
```

then you can use just `Node` when defining variables, like this

```
Node myNode;
```

(but it is probably better to avoid using the same name for the struct and the typedef to avoid confusion).

Note however that you still have to write `struct Node` within your struct when it references itself, because at that point the typedef hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Okay - that definitely was something I missed. Thank you! That has reduced my errors.

But what does strrev.c:16: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers mean? That error is still occurring.

Comment: @katiea You have to terminate your struct definition with a semicolon

Comment: I thought that was a C++ thing..?

Better question: So I complete my understanding, what is the point of the semicolon after the struct definition.

Comment: Because when you define a struct you can at the same time declare a variable of that type, like this: struct { ... } my_variable;. If you don't terminate the struct with a semicolon the compiler will think whatever follows it will be a variable that should have a type of your struct.

Comment: Just one last question. I have a warning:

strrev.c:14: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration

From my understanding, this is because the variable may be a static or instance variable. But this isn't something I need to worry about in this case, right?

Comment: My guess is that it is because of your typedef of your struct. It is not complete as you are not giving it any name. Try removing the typedef if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

If not typedef-ed to anything a structure type name in C has to be preceded by the struct keyword. So instead of

`Node *ptr;`

use

`struct Node *ptr;`

Your strcpy function seems undeclared. For that just : #include `<string.h`>